# Why would one prove that? Counterexample needed.

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

> **Lemma** Let $X$ compact metric space and $K \subset C(X, \mathbb{R})$ the subalgebra containing all constant functions and $f,g \in K$ two functions. Then, $|f|, \max(f,g), \min(f,g) \in \overline{K}$, where $\overline{E}$ denotes the closure of some set $E$.

**Question**
Our proof is rather complicated and seems to be cracking a nut with a sledgehammer. If $f$ and $g$ are constant, aren't $|f|, \max(f,g), \min(f,g)$ also constant functions and therefore trivially in $K$? So why do we even need a the closure at all?

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ are constant then the question is trivial. The problem is when $f$ or $g$ or both are not constant.

Comment: Consider $X=[0,1],$ $f(x)=x$ and $g=0.$  Are you sure $|f|\in K$ for all $K?$

Comment: It is not that easy. Your subalgebra might be larger than just the constant functions. Take for example $K$ to be the subalgebra of all polynomial functions. There it is not easy to see that the conclusion still holds.

Comment: These facts are usually lemmas in showing the Weierstraß approximation theorem.

Comment: You need the closure because the end goal is to show $K$ is dense, so its closure equals the whole function space $C(X,\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: @mfl I don't quite follow: On $[0,1]$ we have $|f| \equiv f$, right? Maybe you meant $X := [-1,1]$, but $|f| = |x| is still continuous.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik You're right. I meant $X=[-1,1].$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already said, just because your subalgebra contains all constant functions, doesn't mean that it consists only of constant functions. So your Question should be answered.